# Why use a hidden field with the method-override package in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I refer to the last example in the [method-override NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override). A hidden field needs to be set when using either PUT or DELETE. Why is this so when the code also works without the hidden field?

```
    <!-- enctype must be set to the type you will parse before methodOverride() -->
<form method="POST" action="/resource" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
  <button type="submit">Delete resource</button>
</form>
```

I've tried the code as below to be working fine without the hidden field:

```
<form action="/ideas/{{idea.id}}?_method=PUT" method="post">
  {{!-- <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"> --}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{idea.title}}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="details">Details</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="details" required>{{idea.details}}</textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Update: My back-end code is as below:

```
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.put("/ideas/:id",(req,res) => {
  res.send("PUT");
})
```

I have the word "PUT" displayed on the browser irregardless of the use of the hidden field.

Comment: Well, you'd have to show us the server code that processes the form submission so we could have some idea what it's trying to do with the form fields.  It totally depends upon what the server code is doing.  There's no rule that you have to put anything in a hidden field, but if the server code expects something to be in a hidden field in order to work properly, then the data needs to be there in a hidden field.  It all depends upon the server code.

Comment: FYI, your link to your method-override NPM reference is busted.

Comment: It looks like if the `?_method=xxxx` is set in the query string, then you don't need the hidden field.  Perhaps you can use one or the other.

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the link.

Comment: @jfriend00, the example is related to front-end usage as per the link I've updated above.

Comment: FYI, here's [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override#override-using-a-query-value) for setting the method with the query string.  No hidden form element required when specifying the method that way.  That's what your second form uses.

Comment: What front-end usage to use depends upon how the back-end server code is configured and coded.  The two aren't independent of one another.

Comment: @jfriend00, okay I understand. I've added the back-end code into my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your form puts `?_method=PUT` in the action URL for the form, then that takes care of specify the method name and you do not need to put it in a hidden form element.  That's why your second form works just fine because it has that in the URL.  It appears you can put the method in either the URL or in a hidden form element.

The doc for putting it in the URL is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override#override-using-a-query-value), but the overall doc is pretty poor for that module so it takes some examination of the code (which is also pretty confusing) to be sure what is going on.

---

And, also in your server code, you are telling the method-override code to look for the `_method` key in the URL or form when you do this:

```
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
```